# Unable to show dialog using Caliburn

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor...

    private readonly IWindowManager _windowManager;
    private readonly Lazy<StartupDialogViewModel> _startupDialog;

    public ShellViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager, 
        Lazy<StartupDialogViewModel> startupDialog)
    {
        _windowManager = windowManager;
        _startupDialog = startupDialog;
    }

    protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view) {

        base.OnViewLoaded(view);

        if(_windowManager.ShowDialog(_startupDialog.Value) == true; // ex

    }
```

**Exception Details**

> Cannot set Owner property to a Window that has not been shown previously.

*Trace*

> at System.Windows.Window.set_Owner(Window value)
>      at Caliburn.Micro.WindowManager.EnsureWindow(Object model, Object view, Boolean isDialog)
>      at Caliburn.Micro.WindowManager.CreateWindow(Object rootModel, Boolean isDialog, Object context, IDictionary`2 settings)
>      at Caliburn.Micro.WindowManager.ShowDialog(Object rootModel, Object context, IDictionary`2 settings)
>      at XXXXX.ShellViewModel.OnViewLoaded(Object view)

What could be the reason of this? I also tried calling the window managers `ShowDialog` within `OnViewReady`, but no luck.

Comment: How are you initialising your `ShellViewModel`?

Comment: you didnt put [ImportingConstructor] ?

Comment: @AminBudianto That's only necessary when using CM together with MEF.

Comment: @xvdiff aah ok its just that i automatically assume MEF will be used with Caliburn, sorry. Actually this error did happen to me but once I move the code to OnViewLoaded it works fine. Maybe you can move your code to another view model. This is how I code mine. ShellViewModel will call MainViewModel, my code is in the OnViewLoaded in the MainViewModel. In ShellViewModel XAML 
    <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />, Code Behind: 
            this.ActivateItem(mainViewModel);